# How does attrs fool the debugger to step into auto generated code?

Tags: python, python-attrs

I'm going through some code which uses the [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/index.html) module. As a result of that when debug stepping through some code, I end up with sources which don't exist as actual files but are auto generated.

This question is about what python technique is used to achieve this behavior. The actual library used for the example or the example itself is just something concrete to show the concept.

#### Example

Install the library

```
virtualenv -p python3 labgrid-venv                                                                                                                                                                      
source labgrid-venv/bin/activate                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
git clone https://github.com/labgrid-project/labgrid                                                                                                                                                               
cd labgrid                                                                                                                                                                                              
pip install -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                                                                         
pip install .
```

The code which exhibits the behavior (`test.py`):

```
from labgrid import Target                                                   
from labgrid.resource import RawSerialPort                                   
 
rpi = Target("RPi")
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
raw_serial_port = RawSerialPort(rpi, None, port="/dev/ttyUSB0", speed=115200)
```

Executing that code and stepping into `RawSerialPort` results the debugger finding itself in a auto generated source:

```
(venv) project_root$ python test.py           
[0] > project_root/test.py(15)<module>()                      
-> raw_serial_port = RawSerialPort(rpi, None, port="/dev/ttyUSB0", speed=115200)                      
(Pdb++) s                                                                                             
--Call--                                                                                              
[1] > <attrs generated init labgrid.resource.serialport.RawSerialPort>(1)__init__()                   
-> def __init__(self, target, name, port=attr_dict['port'].default, speed=attr_dict['speed'].default):
(Pdb++)
```

Notice the `def __init__` definition, no such definition exists in the actual source files, but is auto generated by `attrs`.

My question is what python mechanism is in place here to achieve this behavior which fools even the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the definition of `RawSerialPort` from the [documentation](https://labgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/labgrid/resource/serialport.html#RawSerialPort):

```
@target_factory.reg_resource
@attr.s(eq=False)
class RawSerialPort(SerialPort, Resource):
    """RawSerialPort describes a serialport which is available on the local computer."""
    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        super().__attrs_post_init__()
        if self.port is None:
            ValueError("RawSerialPort must be configured with a port")
```

The class created by the `class` statement is *not* what is ultimately bound to the name `RawSerialPort`; it's whatever object is returned by `target_factory.reg_resource`. The decorator syntax desugars to

```
class RawSerialPort(SerialPort, Resource):
    """RawSerialPort describes a serialport which is available on the local computer."""
[docs]    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        super().__attrs_post_init__()
        if self.port is None:
            ValueError("RawSerialPort must be configured with a port")

RawSerialPort = target_factory.reg_resource(attr.s(eq=False)(RawSerialPort))
```

The original class is passed first to
`attr.s(eq=False)`, which returns a new, augmented class (one that contains the `__init__` method referenced in the debugger session), and *that* class is passed to `target_factory.reg_resource` which (without actually looking up the definition), returns yet another class (possibly the same class) based on whatever the `attr` module created.

So the debugger isn't being fooled; quite the contrary, it's showing *exactly* what is happening, which isn't obvious from looking only at `test.py`.

Comment: What got me confused is that usually the debugger does step into decorators and this doesn't seem to be the case for this example. But you did point correctly that it's a class decorator, and I've only successfully stepped in function ones. Let me confirm this.

Comment: It steps into the decorator if you trace the definition of the function. If you are tracing the *result* of the decoration, you step into (say) the function *returned* by the decorator.

Comment: Which is to say, the decorators have already been applied by the time you call `pdb.set_trace()` in `test.py`. They are called when the class is *defined*, not when you instantiate the class.

Comment: You're right! 
So far I've always assumed that the debugger ends up in the inner function just because that was usually the first line of code in the decorator. Now I know that not to be true

Answer (score 3):

PDB uses the [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html) module to look up the source code of a Python file that you're stepping through.

So when `attrs` creates a new method it does the following:

1. [create](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/32fb12789e5cba4b2e71c09e47196b10763ddd7d/src/attr/_make.py#L1863) a fake, unique file name for each method
2. [compile](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/32fb12789e5cba4b2e71c09e47196b10763ddd7d/src/attr/_make.py#L1877) the generated code to bytecode using the [`compile` builtin](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#compile) and tell it that the code is from that fake file name
3. [attach](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/32fb12789e5cba4b2e71c09e47196b10763ddd7d/src/attr/_make.py#L1887-L1894) the source code it has compiled in step 2 to the filename it has created in step 1 in [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/linecache.html#module-linecache).

Now when pdb stumbles into the method it sees the file name, it will look it up in linecache and has the original source code for stepping through.

---

It was always very important for me to be able to step through whatever attrs generates to take away the notion of magic and *show* what's going on in the code.

Comment: This is great! I'm implementing a library which generates the code on the fly, and need debug into it too.

Comment: Hi hynek, I debug into attrs generated __init__, pycharm just give `<frame not available>`. Is there something wrong?

Comment: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/12445254/196085427-3803087c-4931-493c-8c8a-0ed812db84b4.png)